# Design query Like Datasheet ...Ms Access

Tags: ms-access, subquery

I have a table Exams (ID, StudentID, ExamDate, Subject, Marks)

How can I design a query so that Subjects become headers?

Like

```
Student Name Math | Biology | History | Language...
```

subquery or any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, needed to do a crosstab query... Just now figuring out how best to implement it.